# average grayscale from rgb image in python

Tags: image, python-2.7, image-processing, numpy

I have a RGB image that I split in its three channels (I also have a plot for each channel). How can I obtain a grayscale image by taking the mean across the three channels?
I did

```
    np.average(my_image)
```

and I get the average value back, but if I do

```
    imshow(np.average(my_image)
```

I can't plot the image and actually see it (I got the error: Invalid dimensions for image data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To average over the last axis of `my_image`, use

```
np.average(my_image, axis=-1)
```

If `my_image` has shape `(H, W, 3)`, then `np.average(my_image, axis=-1)` will return an array of shape `(H, W)`.

For example,

```
In [9]: my_image = np.arange(18).reshape((3,2,3))

In [10]: np.average(my_image, axis=-1)
Out[10]: 
array([[  1.,   4.],
       [  7.,  10.],
       [ 13.,  16.]])
```

Without `axis=-1`, `np.average` takes the mean over all values in the array.

```
In [11]: np.average(my_image)
Out[11]: 8.5
```

`imshow` expects an array, not a float. This is why you were getting an "invalid dimension" error.

---

To display the array as a grayscale image using matplotlib:

```
In [24]: arr = np.average(my_image, axis=-1)

In [25]: plt.imshow(arr, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
Out[25]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0xa8f01cc>

In [26]: plt.show()
```

[image]

---

To make a greyscale image using PIL:

```
import Image
import numpy as np

my_image = np.linspace(0, 255, 300*200*3).reshape((300,200,3))
arr = np.average(my_image, axis=-1)

img = Image.fromarray(arr.astype('uint8'))
img.save('/tmp/out.png')
```

[image]

---

Note that there are other ways to convert an RGB image to a grayscale image than by taking the mean. For instance, the luminosity is defined by

```
 0.21 R + 0.72 G + 0.07 B
```

and in practice [tends to produce a better result](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/).

Comment: I've tried the first method and it's perfect for my purpose, thank you!